# UDP Server and Client in Delphi

Tags: delphi, sockets, udp

I am making a UDP C/S. I am having a problem with number of data the server can receive per second.

I have tested sending batches of 10, 100, 1000 data messages to the server, 10, 100 received without a problem. when sending 1000, only 300 ~ 400 received. All tests done on locally.

I have tried implement the server using both ICS's twsocket and Synapse's tudpblocksocket. Both turned out with same problem above.

Could any explain to me why this happens, and how could I improve the server performance.

Code using TUDPBlockSocket

...

```
while not Terminated do
begin
  try
    sz := FUDPServer.WaitingData;
    if sz > 0 then
    begin
      FUDPServer.RecvBuffer(mem.Memory, sz);
      mem.Seek(0, 0);
      AMessage := fFormats.ReadFromStream(mem);
      DoMessageReceived(FUDPServer.RemoteSin.sin_addr, AMessage);
    end; 

  finally

  end;
end;
```

...

Code using ICS

...

```
procedure TShapeServer.WSocketDataAvailable(Sender: TObject; ErrCode: Word);
...
begin
  SrcLen := SizeOf(Src);
  stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  stream.SetSize(INT_BUFFER_SIZE);
  Inc(fMessageReceived);  
  try
    Len    := FUDPServer.ReceiveFrom(stream.Memory, stream.size, Src, SrcLen);
    if (FSenderAddr.S_addr = INADDR_ANY) or
       (FSenderAddr.S_addr = Src.Sin_addr.S_addr) then
    begin

      while stream.Position < Len do
      begin
        try
          AMessage := fFormats.ReadFromStream(stream);
          DoMessageReceived(Src.Sin_addr, AMessage);
        except
          break;
        end;
      end;

    end;

  finally
    stream.Free;
  end;
end;
...
```

Comment: Can you log the loopback udp traffic using wireshark (on Windows it works with winpcap)?

Comment: I'd also look into Microsoft's "security" limit of packet per sec. IIRC, tcpip.sys reported capping action to event log

Comment: I tried wireshark. Not sure if have done it wrong, but there is loopback adapter for me to choose. :(  Great tool tho.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

UDP doesn't guarantee message delivery - if there's no place in the buffer, the packet is dropped without hesitation. 
If you need guaranteed delivery, use TCP and build a message-based communication scheme on top of TCP. Or use our [MsgConnect](http://www.eldos.com/msgconnect/) product which already has it. Note for crusaders: MsgConnect has an open-source version.

Comment: So, is there a way to make the buffer bigger, or to work through the buffer's contents faster?

Comment: @Rob and what the reason is? Even if you could make a buffer huge (and you can't_, you would not have a guarantee that under heavier load the buffer size would be sufficient. And packet drop in that case would cause hard-to-trace bugs. So it's better not to use "flawed" (for this concrete purpose) architecture

Comment: As an experiment, I have increased the buffer size to 4MB on the server and 2MB on the client. That has actually allowed me send 10K without losing any data messages. The application I am going to use it in isn't really data critical, mostly data monitoring. This is actually good enough for me. Plus the concurrent connections tcp allows just isn't enough. Cheers all. :)

Comment: @Darkerstar Do you develop the application for LAN only or for Internet? With Internet the problem is that each router also has various buffers and data loss will happen more frequently there.

Comment: @Darkerstar then I recommend that you do performance tests immediately before you invest more time into this architecture. It can be that loss rate will turn to be unacceptable in real life.

Comment: @Darkerstar BTW in MsgConnect we address this by letting TCP transport disconnect after certain period of inactivity, so the client connects, sends a message and if there are no other messages for certain (configurable) time, it disconnects. This way connections are not kept open.

Comment: To the over-zealous spam flaggers: Not every link to a for-profit product is spam. This post meets all the guidelines mentioned in the FAQ under [self promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use UDP protocol and don't loose any packet, you'll have to add an Acknowledge mechanism to your program, because UDP packets can get lost during the transmission. This ACK mechanism is already implemented in the TCP protocol, so it's the best choice for performance and consistency.

If you can't use TCP (perhaps your client don't have enough CPU power or RAM to handle TCP), consider using some easy to code UDP based protocol, like TFTP. We implemented a TFTP client and server over our [SynCrtUnit](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynCrtSock.pas), but you have such a component in Synapse. But TFTP is slow, because it wait for an ACK signal for every transmitted packet. So you won't loose any packet, but the speed will be poor, compared to TCP.

Last year, I've implemented such TFTP Server in Delphi, then a TFTP Client in TP 7, in a DOS-based automated engine. This was working great, and some object structures were shared between both ends. The TFTP/UDP/IP stack was coded in pure TP 7, with only static allocated memory, and was working great.

But if you don't have such "low CPU" requirements, rather consider using TCP/IP instead of UDP/IP. If you need some broadcasting for example, then use UDP, but with some kind of ACK mechanism.

Comment: Thanks, I will be sure to check it out.

Comment: In fact, when you build UDP-based communication with guaranteed delivery, it's hard to beet TCP in speed: it was polished by generations of developers. It's possible (we did this for certain specific tasks and applications) but quite non-trivial. So going TCP route with possible disconnects on inactivity is probably the best approach.