# How can I use TIdUDPServer in a console application?

Tags: delphi, udp, indy

The Indy UDP server component seems to depend on Windows messages, as I see new messages appear only when the mouse cursor moves over the form which contains the server component.

I created the component at run time using this code:

```
private
    { Private declarations }
    Srv: TIdUDPServer;
...
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Srv := TIdUDPServer.Create(Self);
  Srv.DefaultPort := 9009;
  Srv.OnUDPRead := Self.udpServerUDPRead;
  Srv.Active := True;
end;
```

I would prefer a console or service application. Do I need an (invisible) window handle + some windows message queue code which to get this component working?

Update: some (inofficial) [documentation](http://www.fredshack.com/docs/indy.html) says:

> TIdUDPServer when active creates a listening thread to listen for
>   inbound UDP packets. ... When ThreadedEvent is false, the OnUDPRead
>   event will be fired in the context of the main program thread. When
>   ThreadedEvent is true, the OnUDPRead event is fired in the context of
>   the listener thread.

Comment: This might be useful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359635/udp-server-and-client-in-delphi

Comment: It does not depend on windows messages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use threading then you don't need Windows messages nor forms. Just set ThreadedEvent to true and handle in a thread, remembering that the event is coming in on a different thread so you will have to handle thread "synchronisation". I do this by only using threads that process messages off their own internal queue (my messages and my queue, not Windows messages or queues), so the event handler puts a message with the received data onto the thread's queue, to be processed in the context of the "destination" thread, not the Indy listener thread.