# Delphi indy Remote host UDP client/server

Tags: delphi, udp, client-server, indy

Is it possible to connect to remote host with indy client and send data to the local server.
i try something like this and i don't receive anything:

```
  Server:=TIdUDPServer.Create;
  Server.OnUDPException:=UDPException;
  Server.OnUDPRead:=UDPRead;
  Server.Bindings.Add.Port:=10;
  Server.Active:=true;
  //Server is listening to local IP

  Client:=TIdUDPClient.Create;
  with Client do begin
    Host:= '130.204.159.205'; //My IP
    Port:=10;
    Send('Hello');
  end;
```

My goal is to create client/server applications that will communicate with UDP over internet

Comment: Is it a console or VCL application? For console apps, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647112/how-can-i-use-tidudpserver-in-a-console-application

Comment: Don't forget about firewall and/or anti**virus**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UDP is a connectionless transport.  It does not guarantee data deliver like TCP does, especially over a large network like the Internet.  If `TIdUDPServer` is not receiving data, then either the packets are not reaching the machine to begin with, or are being blocked before `TIdDUPServer` can see them.  Use a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark, to verify that the packets are reaching the NIC(s) that `TIdUDPServer` is listening on.  If they are not, then you have a networking issue.  If they are, then you have an OS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Let's bypass some questions and try this instead:

```
Host := '127.0.0.1'
```

If that doesn't work, check to see if your Windows Firewall allows your test application to connect to itself.  (Turn off local software based firewalls and try it again.)

Comment: dude there is not such variable Host for UDPServer. There is IP:='127.0.0.1'
but its the same i dont receive text

Comment: Dude, I'm not talking HOST, I'm talking CLIENT.  I'm suggesting a validation of your IP address.  Instead of using your public address, attempt to use your localhost address instead (127.0.0.1)

Comment: I dont want to run this program only for my local network
I want my client/server app to connect via Internet on remote host

Comment: One more attempt and then I give up - Try it locally and see what happens.  If it works locally and not from machine to machine, then it points to a network issue / connectivity between the machines and NOT in the software.. It's an attempt to isolate the problem.

Comment: (And it could fail locally as well due to a local software firewall which is why I said to turn off all local firewalls.)

Comment: no locally works
i connect to myself and send and receive data.
but i cannot receive data from my remote IP address

Comment: So... that means the code is likely fine and it's likely networking...like firewalls getting in your way.

Comment: The most probable cause is that you have no port forwarding specified on your router. the packets reach your external public IP but the router does not know where to send them inside the LAN. This is usually a typical issue when dealing with routers and public IP address. Other probable cause is that your router does not recognize your external IP when you try it from inside your LAN. Some routers just block or completely ignore such requests, because it is some sort of loopback.

Comment: If you have two machines at home, just set the server on one and the client on other. Use the internal LAN IP (192.169.X.X) and if that works it will work over public IP also.